# Understanding Arrays and Functions

Tags: c, arrays

The program that I'm showing you asks the user for no. of people and asks each person how many pancakes did the the person eat. Afterwards it prints the biggest number of pancakes.
Okay up until now I found it easy to do.
What I would like to do is (without using pointers) state the person who ate the most.

Here's what I did so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int person, i;
int pancake[50];

printf("Enter Number Of People: ");
scanf("%d", &person);

for (i=1; i<=person; i++)
{
    printf("Person [%d]: ", i);
    scanf("%d",&pancake[i]);
}

for (i=1; i<=person; i++)
  {
    if (pancake[1]<pancake[i])
    {
        pancake[1] = pancake[i];
    }
  }
  printf("Most pancakes eaten is %d\n", pancake[1]);
}
```

Any ideas how to find that or is it necessary for me to use pointers?

Comment: Small typo. `pancakes` should be `pancake`.

Comment: First lesson: Array indices start at `0`. The array length is the first illegal index. So make your loops run from zero to one less than the array length, which you should test with `i < Person` in good C style.

Comment: Note that arrays in C start with 0. The last element of `pancakes[50]` is `pancakes[49]`. You are actually writing outside of your array (typical buffer overrun)

Comment: ohh okay my bad for that will keep that in mind thank you

Comment: Have you read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use pointers. I am posting full modified<sup>1.</sup> code because of many errors/typos in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int person, i;
    int pancake[50];

    printf("Enter Number Of People: ");
    scanf("%d", &person);
    char name[person][30];              // 2D array to store the name of persons. Note that I used variable length arrays. 

   for (i=0; i < person; i++)
   {
       printf("Person [%d]: ", i+1);
       scanf("%d",&pancake[i]);
       printf("Person %d name: ", i+1);
       getchar();                       // To eat up the newline left behind by previous scanf.
       fgets(name[i], 30, stdin);       // To read the persons name. I removed the scanf.
   }

   for (i=0; i<person-1; i++)
   {
       if (pancake[0]<pancake[i+1])
       {
           pancake[0] = pancake[i+1];
           strcpy(name[0] , name[i+1]);  // A function in <string.h> to copy strings.
       }
   }
   printf("Most pancakes eaten is %d by %s \n", pancake[0], name[0]);
}
```

---

<sub>1. Some useful links:

I. [fscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html#tag_16_170).

II. [getchar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar.html#tag_16_189).

III. [strcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcpy.html#tag_16_571).</sub>

Comment: It guess it would be helpful to the OP if you commented the changes you have made to his or her code. The OP seems to have difficulties to understand how arrays in C work. I'm not sure it was a good idea to add the names, which opens a can of string-buffer-overflow and ´scanf`-vs-`fgets` worms and might confuse the OP even more.

Comment: @MOehm; OK. Edited that with some useful links :).

Comment: Yup, looks good. :-) (Aside: Wouldn't it be better to omit the `getchar()` in favour of a `"%d "` format (with trailing space) in `fscanf`? You don't know for sure that the next char is the newline, for example if the user entered `" 42  \n"`.)

Comment: instead of str copying and overwriting your data in the second bit where you are finding the most eaten. you could just obtain the index that has the most and use that... what if he wants to find something else next?

Comment: @MOehm; No. Then you have to press any other character and then `fgets` will read that character. You will not able to enter the name of the persons.

Comment: @UpAndAdam; If you would use pointer then no need to do these things. Its just a small modification to the OP's code. I did't altered it much otherwise OP could have some problem with new code, new logic.

Comment: @haccks: Regarding the input: Both solutions are flawed. I think it's bets not to mix `fscanf` and `fgets`. As for the index: How will keeping an index require pointers? Just print `name[imax]` instead of the very cumbersome use of the first person as temporary storage.

Comment: @MOehm; If you will use the array of pointers then you will need only to increment yor pointer and then print it. That's it.

Comment: @haccks: No-one talks about pointers, except you. What UpAndAdam suggested is to keep an integer index for the person with the most pancakes eaten. Your last comment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MOehm; Yes. I know. I am suggesting pointer here. There are many ways to solve the same problem .

Comment: @haccks The OP said no pointers, he doesn't care what you prefer. The question doesn't concern your opinion. If you are going to provide a solution why not provide a better one since his real problem he is asking about how to find something within an array without pointers..

Comment: @UpAndAdam; In C99, you can omit `return 0;` from `main`.

Comment: @haccks gotcha. I have my warning levels turned up to still not allow that for other reasons. good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of @haccks solution that shows how to do without pointers in an efficient manner. Note the eliminiation of magic numbers into #defines, the return inserted so it compiles

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#declare NUM_PANCAKES 50
#declare NAME_LENGTH_MAX 30

int main(void)
{
    int person, i;
    int pancake[NUM_PANCAKES];
    int best_index = 0;
    int most_pancakes = 0;

    printf( "Enter Number Of People: ");
    scanf( "%d", &person);
    char name[person][NAME_LENGTH_MAX]; /* variable length list... */

    /* get the data */
    for ( i = 0; i < person; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Person [%d]: ", i + 1);
        scanf( "%d", &pancake[i] );
        printf( "Person %d name: ", i + 1 );
        getchar();
        fgets( name[i], NAME_LENGTH_MAX, stdin );
    }

    /* find the answer */
    for ( i = 0; i < person - 1; i++ )
    { 
        if ( pancake[i] > most_pancakes )
        {
            most_pancackes = pancake[i];
            best_index = i;
        }
    }
    printf( "Most pancakes eaten is %d by %s \n", 
           pancake[best_index],
           name[best_index] );

    return 0;
}
```